# import ibm_db error after pip3 install (need help)

Tags: python

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fe3bb08c8a05> in <module>
----> 1 import ibm_db

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
```

(On macOS Big Sur 11.2.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solution for it.

- Install new gcc of version >= 8 in your system and set environment variable to use it so that libstdc++.6.dylib from new version of gcc should get picked up instead of existing old one.
- export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clidriver/lib

Comment: Thank you so much, @milad sadeghi. I don't have the same path but I get the idea from your answer and was able to find one that works with my path at : [https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/tree/master/IBM_DB/ibm_db]  

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clidriver/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`